# How to fix 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined'

Tags: database, filter, repeater, velo

I am trying to display a reference field from my database as a result on my filtered repeater. I am unsure of how to code the page correctly for this to happen.

When testing my code, this is what shows in the developer console:

```
Loading the code for the SEARCH WITH VIN page. To debug this code, open i5zkm.js in Developer Tools.
Url: https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/decodevin/19UUA96299A543965/?format=jsonVINModule.jsw
Line 5{...}
SEARCH WITH VIN
Line 14{...}
VINModule.jsw
Line 12
Dataset is now filtered
SEARCH WITH VIN
Line 22
TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
```

```
import {getVINInfo} from 'backend/VINModule';
import {wixData} from 'wix-data';


$w.onReady(function () {
 //TO DO: Write Your Page Related Code Here:
    }); 

export function button1_click(event, $w) {
 //Add your code for this event here:
    getVINInfo($w("#vininput").value)
        .then(VINInfo => {
            console.log(VINInfo)
                      $w("#results").text = VINInfo.Results[8].Value + "  " + VINInfo.Results[5].Value + "  " + VINInfo.Results[7].Value;
                      $w("#dataset1").setFilter(wixData.filter()
                      .eq("year", VINInfo.Results[8].Value)
                      .eq("make", VINInfo.Results[5].Value)
                      .eq("year", VINInfo.Results[7].Value))

                      .then((results) =>{
                          console.log("Dataset is now filtered");
                          $w("#repeater1").data = results.items;
 let items = "title"

                      }) 
                          .catch((err) => {
                          console.log(err);
        });
        $w("#repeater1").expand();
        })
}
```

I expect the repeater to show the title field from my database but nothing happens to the elements in the repeater and I receive the following in my developer console when previewing the page: TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

dataset setFilter() returns a promise with a void value, so you can't just access the dataset items from that returned promise.
If the repeater isn't already bound to the dataset, you should use getItems():

```
$w("#myDataset").getItems()
  .then( (result) => {
      $w("#repeater1").data = results.items
})
```